# Manage Stock checkbox in woocommerce to be always checked when creating a new product

Tags: stock

Is there a hook that allows setting the Manage Stock checkbox in woocommerce to be always checked when creating a new product?

Thanks!

googled but cant find a code that works

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.